# listbox web service Binding Value get installed programe c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have made a web service to install a program

```
public string GetListapp()
{


    string result = "";
    string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
    {
        foreach (string sbnm in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(sbnm))
            {
                string appVersion = (string)subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                String app = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));



                if (app != "")
                    result += appVersion + app + "\r\n";


            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

I also created a simple interface. It works fine with textbox but I also need to get displayname displayversion & publisher

I made this first:

```
 private void btnGIA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MYS.ServiceClient pk = new MYS.ServiceClient();
        textBox1.Text = pk.GetListapp();

    }
```

but now i need to add this to listbox

```
 MYS.ServiceClient pk = new MYS.ServiceClient();
 listBox.ItemsSource = pk.GetListapp();
```

but when I do that and I select a template in listbox like this

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ListBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="91*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="106*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="113*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding result}" Width="Auto"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DisplayVersion}" Width="Auto"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Grid.Column="2" Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

I click on a button but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the ListBox's ItemsSource property to an IEnumerable, i.e. typically some kind of collection of some objects.

Since your GetListapp() method only returns a single string you could create a List<string> and add the string that you get back from the service to this one:

```
MYS.ServiceClient pk = new MYS.ServiceClient();
listBox.ItemsSource = new List<string> { pk.GetListapp(); }
```

The other option would be to return an object with two properties from the service method. Create a class:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string DisplayVersion { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

...and return a list of such objects from the service:

```
public List<MyItem> GetListapp()
{

    List<MyItem> items = new List<MyItem>();
    string registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(registry_key))
    {
        foreach (string sbnm in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(sbnm))
            {
                string appVersion = (string)subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                String app = Convert.ToString(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));

                if (app != "")
                    items.Add(new MyItem() { DisplayName = app, DisplayVersion = appVersion });
            }
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

You could then set the ItemsSource property of the ListBox to this list directly:

```
MYS.ServiceClient pk = new MYS.ServiceClient();
listBox.ItemsSource = pk.GetListapp();
```

...and use an ItemTemplate (not a ControlTemplate) to define the appearance of the items in the ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayVersion}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response really awesome i will try to do that now